# Android: orderBy only using first digit

Tags: android, sorting, sql-order-by

I'm creating a SQLite database where it is possible to make entries for a specific day in the month. I've made a column for the day-number. The entries come in random order, so i wanna sort them. But when i use the orderBy it only sort the numbers by the first digit. 
Example: the entry order is (2,31,5,21,16,9,7). When i then sort it i get the order (16,2,21,31,5,7,9). Is there a way to fix this?

My entry code

```
        public void createEntry(int id, int month, int day, int start_hour, int start_min, int stop_hour, int stop_min) 
        {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        ourDatabase.beginTransaction();
        cv.put(ROW_ID, id);
        cv.put(MONTH,month);
        cv.put(DAY,day);
        cv.put(START_HOUR,start_hour);
        cv.put(START_MIN,start_min);
        cv.put(STOP_HOUR,stop_hour);
        cv.put(STOP_MIN,stop_min);
        ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        ourDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
        ourDatabase.endTransaction();
    }
```

And my code where i sort the data

```
        public ArrayList<String> getDays(){
        String[] columns = new String[]{MONTH, DAY, START_HOUR, START_MIN, STOP_HOUR, STOP_MIN};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, DAY);
        c.moveToLast();
        ArrayList<String> navne = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            Log.d("Entry", c.getString(1));
            navne.add(c.getString(1)+": "+c.getString(2)+":"+c.getString(3)+" - "+c.getString(4)+":"+c.getString(5));
        }
        return navne;


            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + 
                    ROW_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    MONTH + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    DAY + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    START_HOUR + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    START_MIN+ " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    STOP_HOUR + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    STOP_MIN + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
                    );

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ordering alphabetically. Try:

```
ORDER BY ABS(column_name) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't show the definition of the table. Is the DAY column numeric or string?
You would see this behavior if it is a string.

Comment: I guess it is string. I'm not sure how to change that. I've posted the  createTable.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your field like TEXT, the ORDER BY clausole work like if the field is a String. You need to declare it like INTEGER or LONG if you want a numeric order.